# Can I change GCP Dataproc cluster from Standard (1 master, N workers) to High Availability?

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing, upgrade

I have created a GCP Dataproc cluster with Standard (1 master, N workers). Now I want to upgrade it to  High Availability (3 masters, N workers) -  Is it possible?

I tried GCP, GCP alpha and GCP beta commands. For example GCP beta documented here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataproc/clusters/update.

It has option to scale worker nodes, however does not have option to switch from standard to high availability mode. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may always **upgrade your master node machine type** and also add more worker node.
While that would improve your cluster job performance but noting to do with HA.

Answer (score 3):

You can upgrade the master node by going into VM Instances section under your cluster , Stop your Master VM and Edit the configuration to

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can always do that, for changing the machine type of master node
you first need to stop the master VM instance, then you can change the machine type
Even the machine type of worker node can be changed, only we need to do is stop the machine and edit the machine configuration.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is - no. Once HA cluster is created, it can't be downgraded and vice versa. You can add worker nodes, however master node can't be altered.

Comment: Please delete this answer. This is not true and initially it showed up on my google search results as the first result. You simply have to go via Compute Engine and modify the master VM instance.